# Teams: Can You Add Members To A Team And Not Generate The 'Welcome To / Intro To Teams' Email?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-teams

I'm creating a new Team and I have to add new user to this Team but I don't want that the users receive the welcome email.

[image]

I had tried to disable this function with a rule filter in Exchange and with this command in PowerShell

```
Set-UnifiedGroup $groupName -UnifiedGroupWelcomeMessageEnabled:$false

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-unifiedGroup | Select-object -Property DisplayName, WelcomeMessageEnabled

DisplayName               WelcomeMessageEnabled
-----------               ---------------------
MyTeam                            False
```

But nothing of this works fine and the new users are receiving this emails.

How can I do it?

Regards

Comment: Are you trying to create team using Graph API?if yes You can disable notification at the time of [Creating group](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-groups?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http).To disable email notification you need to set "resourceBehavirOptions" to "WelcomeEmailDisabled". Here is an example:Url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups
Request Body:{"displayName": "TestGroup-01","groupTypes": ["Unified"],"mailEnabled": true,"mailNickname": "testgroup-01","resourceBehaviorOptions":["WelcomeEmailDisabled"],"securityEnabled": false,"visibility": "Private",}

Comment: Hi @Nikitha-MSFT, Thanks for your reply. I haven't used Graph API. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: We cannot restrict the mails if you create team manually.You can stop mails using powershell command as you mentioned above after changing WelcomeMessageEnabled from true to false ,You need to wait for the AD replication.